# laravel pagination doesn't keep value

Tags: laravel, pagination

i'm using laravel paginate, but when i change page like 2,3.. it doesn t keep my research value.

**blade**

```
 {{ $items->appends(['list' => $list])->links() }}
```

**controller**

```
if (!empty($request['search'])){
            $list = '';

            $items = Items::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request['search']. '%')->paginate($this->pagination);

        } 
        elseif(!empty($request['list'])){     

            $list= $request['list'];

            $items = Items::where('list_type', 'LIKE', $request['list']. '%')
                                ->orderBy('name')->paginate($this->pagination);

        }
        else{

            $list= '';

            $items = Client::where('list_type', 'LIKE', $request['list']. '%')
                                ->orderBy('name')->paginate($this->pagination);
```

Comment: If you mean that the pagination is not keeping the search value its because you're not appending it to the links. You're not setting the `$list` variable with the value from the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
{{ $items->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```